# Passing a class' own methods as arguments to constructor: how does this work?

Tags: java, syntax

Today I was looking at some prewritten code for a project I am working on and stumbled across something I had never seen before: arguments to a constructor that consisted of the class' own methods. Here is an example

```
SampleFw sampleFramework = new SampleFw(getName(), getType());
```

In this case getName() and getType() are both methods defined only in SampleFw. What exactly happens when this call to the constructor is made?

Comment: You're not passing methods, you're passing the result of their execution.

Comment: Is this code located inside a `SampleFw` method? You're not calling the new `SampleFw`'s methods; you're calling `this`'s methods, or possibly static methods.

Comment: We cannot really tell what's going on as you haven't shown where this one statement is located and what the code around it looks like.  Out of context, this question cannot be completely answered.  We need to know the class and method within which the statement is located.

Answer (score 3):

> arguments to a constructor that consisted of the class' own methods

No, that's not what this code does. It **calls** `getName()` and `getType()`, and passes the values returned by these methods to the constructor. So it's equivalent to

```
String name = getName();
String type = getType(); // assuming it's a String
SampleFw sampleFramework = new SampleFw(name, type);
```

Comment: The problem here is not that the answer does not help the OP, it is that the OP's question doesn't have enough context to be completely answered.

Comment: The OP asked one question and this answers that question. It's not JB's responsibility to read minds, although it might be good to throw out some guesses as to why the developer may have chosen to do things that way.